# split file to specific sizes with tar command

Tags: linux, split, tar

There is an iso file with 5.5 GB in size. I want to split that with tar command each part should be 500M. What is the command for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split`:

```
tar [your params] |split -b 500m - output_prefix
```

...Or use `zip` (or any other compressor):

```
tar [your params] | zip  -s 500m output.zip  -
```

Comment: Thank you, my zip binary has no -s modifier. I've install 7zip instead and success.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the job of tar to split files. Use `split` to split the tar file.

Comment: i have no split, also my zip has no -s modifier. My solution was to install 7zip to do.